# Python Classes: behavior of calling class methods inside constructor

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.say_hello()

    def say_hello(self):
        print(f"Hi my name is {self.name} and I am {self.age}")

user = User("Cristian", 19)
```

output:

```
**Hi my name is Cristian and I am 19**
```

Hello! I have a question about this code. We know that when we create an instance of a class, the constructor is executed, right?; in the code we can see a `say_hello` method that is called inside the constructor, how is this possible if the `say_hello` method is created after the constructor, how can we call something that is not previously defined?

Comment: When you create an instance of the class, the whole class has been defined. Also Python doesn't resolve references like `say_hello()` until it's actually executing the code.

Comment: Right.  That's a key point.  The code in the constructor is not executed until you create an object -- in the last line of your example.  By that time, the class has been  completely read and parsed.  As long as `say_hello` has been defined by that point, it's all good.

Comment: "Defining a method inside the constructor" would look like `self.say_hello = lambda: ...` inside `__init__`. Which is not what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, the `say_hello()` method is defined before it is called. The `say_hello()` is called from `__init__()` that's true, but `__init__()` is called when you are creating your object `user = User("Cristian", 19)`

So the statement responsible for calling `say_hello()` is creation of object and definition of `say_hello()` appears before it is called.

Hope this suffice your query.